# python string module vs str methods

Tags: python

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'happy cat'
>>> string.find(s, 'cat')
6
```

and

```
>>> s = 'happy cat'
>>> s.find('cat')
6
```

In the above 2 pieces of code, i have the following doubts.

1. Why is the 2nd code working without import the string module?
2. Is there any performance improvement in using one over the other?

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: Why is the 1st piece of code working at all, is my question!

Comment: @wim: The first piece of code isn't working. It cannot work. It has to be string.find('happy cat', 'cat')

Comment: @fuuman: fixed typo in example code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functions defined in `string` module that are nowadays methods of `str` were deprecated in [**Python 2.4**](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node111.html) and should not be used at all, though they were retained in later Python 2 versions for backward-compatibility. They were removed in Python 3.0.

> 1. Why is the 2nd code working without import the string module?

Because it's a method of `str` type.

> 2. Is there any performance improvement in using one over the other?

Well, `string.find(x, y)` calls `x.find(y)`, but the performance doesn't matter here (see first sentence).